# Como puedo dar formato de fecha a una fecha importada desde excel y que es un string?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy importando un archivo de excel a mi sistema, pero al momento de importarlo me da un error. Ya que el formato dateTime no es correcto porque viene de esta forma YYYmmdd y es un string. Debo cambiar el dato a tipo date con este formato yyy-m-d.

Estoy usando maatwebsite excel para importar el archivo.

Este es el error de la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi método para importación.

```
class ReportesImport607 implements ToModel, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading
```

{

```
use Importable;


public function model(array $row)
{
    $usuario = User::select('name')->get()->first();
    
    
    return new Factura([
        'cliente_id'        => 1,
        'tipo_factura'      => '607',
        'documento'         => $row[0],
        'tipo_documento'    => $row[1],
        'ncf'               => $row[2],
        'ncf_modificado'    => $row[3],
        'tipo_ingreso'      => $row[4],
        'date_comp'         => $row[5],
        'date_reten'        => $row[6],
        'operador'          => $usuario,

    ]);
}
```

Comment: Agrega cual es el formato de la fecha que te llega, cual es el que deseas otorgar y el error obtenido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolvi de esta manera:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    $usuario = User::select('name')->get()->first();
    $input = $row[5]; 
    $date = strtotime($input); 
    
    
    return new Factura([
        'cliente_id'        => 1,
        'tipo_factura'      => '607',
        'documento'         => $row[0],
        'tipo_documento'    => $row[1],
        'ncf'               => $row[2],
        'ncf_modificado'    => $row[3],
        'tipo_ingreso'      => $row[4],
        'date_comp'         => date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $date),
```

igual para todos los casos donde hay una fecha.

Comment: Bien, no olvides cuando el sistema lo permita marcar como aceptada tu respuesta